# Call child react navigation prop from super component in react-native / react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, drawer

I have a react native application using react navigation. I have following structure in my application.

```
class MainContainer extends Component {

render() {
    return (

    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

    <Header
      backgroundColor={appcolors.primaryColor}
      leftComponent={<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer() }><Feather name='align-justify' size={24} color='white' /></TouchableOpacity>}
      centerComponent={{ text: this.props.headerTitle , style: { color: 'white' } }}
    />

    <MainDrawerNavigation/>

    </View>

   );
}
};
```

and `<MainDrawerNavigation/>` is a react navigation component as follows.

```
MainDrawerNavigation = createDrawerNavigator({
    XScreen: {
      screen: XScreen,
    },
    YScreen: {
      screen: YScreen,
    },
    ZScreen: {
      screen: ZScreen,
    },
},{
  }
});
```

I have got error when trying to call `this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer()` from `MainContainer`. Then for testing purpose I have add a button to `XScreen` and tried to toggle drawer and it was success. So I want to know is there any way to pass child navigation props to super view. So I could call `this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer()` method and control drawer from `MainContainer`. or any navigation practices that can be use to solve this.

PS: the error I got is `_this2.props.navigation.toggleDrawer is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

In `MainContainer`, the `this.props.navigation` is not initiated, so you got such error. You can only access it inside the child component of `MainDrawerNavigation` i.e. XScreen, YScreen & ZScreen only.

For best practices you need to design how all component will navigate into your app and pass `Navigator` objects/components as root component.

There are multiple navigators, you will can read them [react navigation api doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/api-reference.html).

A simplified app needs SwitchNavigator, DrawerNavigator, TabBarNavigator & StackNavigator.

#### SwitchNavigator :

It is used for user authentication. It will give control to toggle between two component (FYI, component can be a Navigator or React.Component).

```
export const AuthNavigator = SwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: { screen: AuthLoadingScreen },
    App: { screen: AppDrawer},
    Auth: { screen: AuthStack}
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
);
```

[for more details](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html)

#### DrawerNavigator :

It is used to display side panel or sliding view at left or right side of the screen. So, you can directly pass this component to SwitchNavigator's authentication successful screen.

```
export default const AppDrawer = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: TabBarNav },
    Notes: { screen: NotesStack },
    Invite: { screen: InviteContactsStack },
    Files: { screen: FilesStack },
    Settings: { screen: SettingsStack }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "#e91e63"
    },
    contentComponent: props => <LeftSidePanel {...props} />
  }
);
```

#### TabBarNavigator :

It is used to display tab bar at bottom for iOS and at top for android by default. This can be customized.

```
export default const TabBarNav = TabNavigator(
  {
    ChatsTab: {
      screen: ChatsStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Chats"
      }
    },
    InviteContacts: {
      screen: InviteContactsStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Invite"
      }
    },
    Notifications: {
      screen: NotificationsStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Notifications"
      }
    },
    Tasks: {
      screen: TasksStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: "Tasks"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    tabBarPosition: "bottom",
  }
);
```

#### StackNavigator :

It's name suggests that it will hold a stack of component. So, when any item is selected from drawer, you can directly put a StackNavigator in that screen.

```
export default const ChatsStack = StackNavigator({
  Chats: {
    screen: Chats
  },
  Messages: {
    screen: Messages
  }
});
```

You can read [Spencer Carli's blog on medium](https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/building-an-authentication-flow-with-react-navigation-fb5de2203b5c) which explain with code.

Please let me know whether it satisfies your need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case I cannot pass <DrawerNavigation> into main stack navigation. because there should be a header thats why

Comment: @SathinduKavneth, you should not put DrawerNavigation inside a StackNavigation becuase you will hold memory for that. better you may put StackNavigation inside DrawerNavigation as I describe in the example.